# Is the composition of Poisson processes a Poisson process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $N_1(t), t \ge 0$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, and let $N_2(t), t \ge 0$ be a Poisson process with the unit rate 1. Is the composition $N_1(N_2(t))$ a Poisson process as well?

I tried looking this up but I couldn't find a clear answer if Poisson processes are closed under composition, but if they are, it would be interesting to know (and also what the resulting rate would be).

Comment: It is not a Poisson process, but rather it is a [*compound Poisson process*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Compound_Poisson_processes).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. Is a compound Poisson process also a Markov process?

Comment: It is not only a Markov process, but is in fact a [*Lévy process*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_process). In particular, it possesses strong Markov property.

Comment: I suppose you assume that the Poisson processes are independent; otherwise you might run into some trouble.